# Yeoman generators, grunt: proper usage of grunt-usemin with grunt-rev

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I have a problem with `grunt-usemin` and `grunt-rev`.

At first the simple workflow to set up an issue environment:

1. Create web application using `yo webapp` generator (the same thing
   with generator-angular).
2. Run grunt.
3. Grunt successfully finished build.

OK, at this point let's navigate to 'dist/scripts'. Here the revisioned version of the `main.js` (for example `01d39df5.main.js`) file located (this is correct due to usage of grunt-rev). The same thing with the `main.css` file - in the 'dist/styles' directory only revisioned version located.

But the problem is that `index.html` contains references to the not revisioned files `main.js` and `main.css`. As I understand, the `grunt-usemin` works or configured wrong.

Could somebody point me to the proper usage of `grunt-rev` in addition with `grunt-usemin`?

Comment: Do you happen to run Windows? There's a bug in usemin at the moment that prevents it from finding and replacing revved files.

Comment: @passy Yes, exactly. Could you please point me to the bug mentioned somewhere?

Comment: @passy I've found [it](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/3). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows grunt.file.expand pattern search bug [has been fixed](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/pull/82) in grunt-usemin v0.1.11.  I just tested `yo webapp` followed by `grunt --force` on Windows and `dist\index.html` now contains references to the revisioned names for the css and js files.